# Is this a Lamport signature?

Tags: signature

One-time public-private key pairs are used. The next public-private key pair to be used, is recorded with a proof `c = sha3(nextPublicKey)`.

Comment: I see at most a commitment for the next public key. I do not see a signature scheme!

Answer (score 1):

No, Lamport signature is a *particular* one-time signature scheme prescribing a particular method of verifying signatures, generating key pairs, and generating signatures.  You could use that technique to turn a one-time signature scheme such as Lamport's into a *tremendously awkward* stateful many-time signature scheme.